# ¿Se puede configurar en MySQL el uso dos bases de datos al mismo tiempo?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, configuración, mysql-connect

¡Hola a todos!
Tengo un sitio web, desarrollado en PHP, en un servidor aparte de la base de datos
que esta en otro servidor.

Mi sitio se conectaba a dos bases de datos simultáneamente, sin ningún tipo de problema,
al cambiar la base de datos de servidor, surgió un problema que no reconocía las dos conexiones,
lo solucione seteando true en el parámetro new link de la función mysql_connect.

```
$link_web = mysql_connect($host_web,$user_web,$pass_web, true)
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿se puede solucionar este problema seteando la variable :
sql.safe-mode a 'on' en el php.ini?

No lo he querido probar, ya que es un sistema que esta contantemente operativo
y esto requeriría de un reinicio de servidor, que por el momento prefiero evitar.

¿O existe alguna otra forma de solucionar este problema sin modificar el código?
ya que antes de migrar la base a un servidor nuevo, el sitio web mismo funcionaba
sin problemas.

Comment: ¿Y por qué deberías mantener el sitio web en un servidor y la base de datos en otro servidor? ¿No es mejor tener todo en el mismo servidor? Sea como sea, faltan detalles en la pregunta. Por ejemplo, ¿cuál es el entorno, hosting compartido u otro? ¿Qué justificaría que sitio web y base de datos estén separados? Si eso debe ser así, quizá deberías plantearte hacer las solicitudes a la base de datos cURL, talvez sea menos lento y menos peligroso que manejar una conexión remota, no sé, tu planteamiento es muy extraño y no creo que tenga justificación mantener algo así.

Comment: @A.Cedano tener la BBDD es muy natural cuando deployas a la nube. Una misma BBDD puede alimentar varios sistemas desacoplados. La web, el dashboard de administración, los reportes, etc. Pueden existir como microservicios en otras máquinas o derechamente serverless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de la extensión `php_mysql` [está descontinuado desde la versión 5.5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) que data de hace ocho años. Las modificaciones que hay que hacer para cambiar a la sintaxis de `mysqli` son menores, y de verdad es urgente migrar.

Dicho esto, en tu pregunta señalas que el uso de dos conexiones dejó de funcionar cuando cambiaste de servidor. ¿Qué cambió exactamente? Lo pregunto porque si abres dos conexiones al mismo servidor el comportamiento esperado es que el driver reutilice la conexión que ya está abierta. Ej

```
   $conn1 = mysql_connect($host_web,$user_web,$pass_web);
   var_dump($conn1);
   // imprime "resource(xxx) of type (mysql connect) array(0) { }"

   $conn2 = mysql_connect($host_web,$user_web,$pass_web);
   var_dump($conn1 === $conn2);
   // imprime "bool(true)"
```

Para forzar una conexión nueva se hace tal cual lo haces ahora. Pasando como `true` el cuarto parámetro,`$new_link`.

**Con respecto al uso de *safe-mode***: no. Safe mode debiera provocar que el parámetro `$new_link` sea ignorado silenciosamente. Su utilidad real es que añade algunas salvaguardas a la ejecución de sentencias. Por ejemplo, si alguien pone

```
UPDATE orders SET refund=true 
-- WHERE id=10
```

el driver no lo dejará hacer ese update masivo por accidente. Esto no es un tema de PHP, de todos modos. Es un setting de sesión de mysql.

Cuando hagas la migración al driver mysqli (o bien a PDO) no será necesario forzar la creación de una conexión paralela, puesto que el método `mysqli_connect` no devuelve un resource en el scope global, sino una instancia de `mysqli` encapsulada y autocontenida.

```
   $conn1 = mysqli_connect($host_web,$user_web,$pass_web);       
   var_dump($conn1 === $conn2);
   // imprime object(mysqli)#1 (6) { ... }

   $conn2 = mysqli_connect($host_web,$user_web,$pass_web); 
   var_dump($conn1 === $conn2);
   // imprime bool(false)
```

La función  `mysqli_connect` es en realidad [un alias para el constructor de la clase mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), cosa que sea más fácil asimilar los pequeños cambios en la sintaxis.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Lo que cambiamos fue la versión de la base de datos MySQL 5.5.50 a MariaDB 10.5.6 y eso provocó que tuviéramos el problema, cuando se tenía que consultar por la primera base de datos siempre lo hacía con la base de datos 2. Nosotros queremos saber si fue un tema de configuración en la anterior base de datos mysql, que en las versiones nuevas quizás no lo tiene habilitado. Porque antes del cambio del servidor funcionaba.

Comment: Puede que esté habilitado safe mode por defecto. Ejecuta `SELECT @@sql_mode;` a ver qué tiene seteado